# Парсинг XML данных с сокета TCP на python 3

Tags: python-3.x, xml, сокет, unicode, tcp

Только начинаю свой путь программиста и пишу свою первую программу. Уже неделю бьюсь вот над какой задачей:
Необходимо написать утилиту, которая слушала бы TCP порт другого ПО и обрабатывала с него данные. Данные приходят в XML формате.  Здесь на лицо схема: Клиент (ПО которое предает XML данные) => сервер, который слушает порт, парсит XML и затем формирует из распарсенных данных сообщения, которые передает на другое устройство по TCP.
Я написал код сервера с вложенным в него парсером, пока без условий и т.д. Хотя бы чтобы посмотреть и проверить. Но ничего не выходит. Догадываюсь, что проблема либо в самом соединении с сокетом (хотя через telnet проверял, все ок, вижу данные), или проблема с кодировкой. Здесь вообще запутался. Прошу у вас помощи!
Пример кода (сервер):

```
import socket
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5555))  # Инициализирует ip-адрес и порт.
# При этом проверяется, не занят ли порт другой программой.

sock.listen(1)  # Устанавливает количество клиентских соединений,
# которые будет обслуживать операционная система.

conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Блокирует приложение до тех пор, пока не придет сообщение от клиента.
# Функция возвращает кортеж из двух параметров – объект самого соединения и адрес клиента.
print('Connected by', addr)

conn.settimeout(10)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(524288)  # читает данные из сокета.
    # Аргумент устанавливает максимальное количество байтов в сообщении.
    udata = data.decode()
    if not data:
        print('No data')
        break
    tree = ET.parse(udata)  # Функция принимает имя файла или файлоподобный объект.
    # Эта функция выполняет синтаксическй анализ данных за раз.
    root = tree.getroot()  # Функция parse() возращает объект, который является представлением всего документа
    entries = tree.findall('elem')  # findall() возвращает список элементов ROOT:elem.
    title_element = entries[0].find('Acknowleged')  # Метод find() принимает запрос ElementTree
    # и возвращает первый удовлетворяющий запросу элемент.
    text = title_element.text
    print("Received data: \n" + udata)
    print("Perser text: \n" + text)
    conn.send("Thanks".encode())
conn.close()  # Закрывает сокет.
```

Пример кода (клиент):

```
import socket

conn = socket.socket()
conn.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5555))  # Позволяет соединиться с сервером.
conn.settimeout(3)
msg = open("XML_example.xml", "r")
read_data = msg.read().encode()
conn.send(read_data)  # Отсылает считанные с файла данные на сервер.
answer = conn.recv(524288)  # Получает данные (ответ) от сервера.
print("SEND DATA: \n" + read_data.decode())
print("ANSWER: \n" + answer.decode())
conn.close()  # Закрывает сокет.
```

пример XML_example.xml данных которые приходят на порт:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
<ROOT>
<elem>
<Acknowleged>1</Acknowleged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>1</Actual>
<ID>101807392</ID>
<Text>20.05 13:21 abacaba</Text>
<Time>12761054477596.000000</Time>
</elem>
<elem>
<Acknowleged>1</Acknowleged>
<Active>0</Active>
<Actual>0</Actual>
<ID>101465016</ID>
<Text>20.05 13:21 dabacaba</Text>
<Time>12761054486487.000000</Time>
</elem>
</ROOT>
```

Что видно в Telnet:[image: telnet]

Ошибка которая появляется при выполнении кода сервера: [image: ошибка]

Comment: А в чем вопрос / проблема? У вас данные влезут в 1024 байта? Что-то сомневаюсь, нужно все данные прочитать. Да и не написали клиента-совета, который отправляет xml. Делал пример отправки и получения json, мб что-то полезное из этого возьмете: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/d884117f7d67cf046eb1f9e226cc8b82cd34a493/socket__tcp__examples/send_recv_json

Comment: Да, согласен с рамером данных напортачил. Увеличил до 512 кб. Но ничего не поменялось. Тут не нужен клиент который отправляет XML. Этот клиент отдельное ПО которое скидывает сообщения в порт TCP, но в формате XML, я приводил пример в скриншоте Telnet. На данном этапе мне надо эти данные увидеть, и просто распарсить их. А по факту дальше    чем conn, addr = sock.accept()  программа не выполняется, или выполняется, не ясно, но распарсенных данных я не вижу.

Comment: Если бы можно было запустить обе части -- сервер и клиент TCP и у себя проверить и исправить было бы отлично, а так хз что у вас не работает. Причин может быть очень много. Поэтому на этому сайте есть рекомендации о написании вопросов, например о том [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Сейчас попробую написать небольшой клиент. Тобы отправлял данные на порт. И дальше отпишусь по результатм, мало ли кому понадобиться =)

Comment: Как сделаете, добавьте его в вопрос вместе с отправляемой xml :)

Comment: Готово! Сделал клиент, который считывает (внимание) с txt файла данные xml в бинарном виде. И отправляет на порт. Но блин, все равно не работет "сервер". Выдает ошибку.

Comment: Сервер ругается `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<?xml version="1.0" encodi` так и должно быть? :)

Comment: Мой косяк, уже поправил. Там файл с xml данными не XML.txt должен быть, а XML_example.xml Т.е. берется не текстовый формат .txt, а .xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось кое-что поменять, но заработало.

Проблема была в `tree = ET.parse(udata)`, дело в том, что первый аргумент принимает путь к файлу или файловый объект, т.е. передавая в него `xml` строку вы заставляли парсер считать что это путь к файлу.

Чтобы это обойти, передавал парсеру файловый объект, созданный через `io.BytesIO`.

Код:

```
import socket
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5555))  # Инициализирует ip-адрес и порт.
# При этом проверяется, не занят ли порт другой программой.

sock.listen(1)  # Устанавливает количество клиентских соединений,
# которые будет обслуживать операционная система.

conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Блокирует приложение до тех пор, пока не придет сообщение от клиента.
# Функция возвращает кортеж из двух параметров – объект самого соединения и адрес клиента.
print('Connected by', addr)

conn.settimeout(10)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(524288)  # читает данные из сокета.
    print("Received data ({}): {}\n".format(len(data), data))

    if not data:
        print('No data')
        break

    tree = ET.parse(io.BytesIO(data))  # Функция принимает имя файла или файлоподобный объект.
    # Эта функция выполняет синтаксическй анализ данных за раз.
    root = tree.getroot()  # Функция parse() возращает объект, который является представлением всего документа
    entries = tree.findall('elem')  # findall() возвращает список элементов ROOT:elem.
    title_element = entries[0].find('Acknowleged')  # Метод find() принимает запрос ElementTree
    # и возвращает первый удовлетворяющий запросу элемент.
    text = title_element.text

    print("Perser text: " + text)
    
    conn.send("Thanks".encode())

conn.close()  # Закрывает сокет.
```

Консоль:

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 12966)
Received data (400): b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>\n<ROOT>\n<elem>\n<Acknowleged>1</Acknowleged>\n<Active>0</Active>\n<Actual>1</Actual>\n<ID>101807392</ID>\n<Text>20.05 13:21 abacaba</Text>\n<Time>12761054477596.000000</Time>\n</elem>\n<elem>\n<Acknowleged>1</Acknowleged>\n<Active>0</Active>\n<Actual>0</Actual>\n<ID>101465016</ID>\n<Text>20.05 13:21 dabacaba</Text>\n<Time>12761054486487.000000</Time>\n</elem>\n</ROOT>'

Perser text: 1
Received data (0): b''

No data
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду сейчас перебирать код, сам факт того, что ошибки нет уже достижение))